# May I let my web browser save my browsing session during Chol Hamoed?

Tags: halacha, technology, chol-hamoed, rav-shlomo-z-auerbach

To save electricity, I like to shut down my computer every night. First, I quit my Web browser.

My Web browser is set up so that, when I quit, it automatically saves my [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#Browser_session_management): a list of open tabs and more. It stores the session on my computer's hard drive. I find this very useful.

R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach was strict about saving information to a computer's hard drive during Chol Hamoed. In ["Chol Hamoed Observance in Modern Times"](http://koltorah.org/ravj/Chol%20Hamoed%20Observance%20in%20Modern%20Times.htm), R' Howard Jachter explains:

> Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (cited in *Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchata* 66 note 209) [...] surprisingly forbids [...] storing information on a computer because it is a form of "building."

Let's say that my rabbi holds like R' Auerbach regarding saving on Chol Hamoed. If so, then during Chol Hamoed, may I quit my Web browser normally and let it save its session? Or must I take special steps so that it won't save its session?

[CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: If you don't want to store anything on your harddrive you will need to do a lot more than not close your browser.

Comment: The browser doesn't save the session on shutdown - it saves it constantly. If you wanted to avoid the browser saving anything you'd need to use "Private browsing mode". But the computer does quite a bit more than just save a session.

Comment: Note that he also forbids typing on the computer in the first place, so it seems to be a moot point.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that R Shlomo Zalman would probably not allow one to use a modern-day computer on *chol hamoed*; a computer constantly saves and re-writes information. However, if this problem is avoided and you are solely concerned about saving browsing information, shut that mode off and use incognito browsing.

Comment: A source for your assumption would greatly improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: @DannySchoemann it seems to follow directly from what's in the question.

Comment: @msh210 Au contraire; the OP quotes RSZA as "forbids [...] storing information on a computer" which implies that one may use the computer, just not "write to disk".

Comment: @DannySchoemann most uses of a typical modern computer, if not all, store information on it.